# How to send form data to multiple email addresses using PHP?

Tags: php, forms

I am a web designer, and dont really know much about PHP. I have a form, and I want the values to be sent to three email addresses.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="player" method="post" action="process.php">

    <label for="name">Your Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" title="Enter your name" class="required">

    <label for="phone">Daytime Phone</label>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" class="required">

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" title="Enter your e-mail address" class="required email">


    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="I'd like to join Now" />

</form>
```

I have somehow found a PHP code that should send the data to ONE email address only, but I dont even know if it works or not.

Here is the code for that:

```
<?php
// Get Data 
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
$url = strip_tags($_POST['url']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

// Send Message
mail( "you@youremail.com", "Contact Form Submission",
"Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone: $phone\nWebsite: $url\nMessage: $message\n",
"From: Forms <forms@example.net>" );
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes you should just use a bit of google, if you google 'php send mail to multiple addresses' you get some really useful hits, the first one being the PHP manual for the mail function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
All you need is on there, right near the top of the page, just remember, google is your friend ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add headers

```
 <?php
 // Get Data 
 $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
 $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
 $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
 $url = strip_tags($_POST['url']);
 $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

 $headers .="From: Forms <forms@example.net>";
 $headers .="CC: Mail1 <Mail1@example.net>";
 $headers .=", Mail2 <Mail2@example.net>";

 // Send Message
 mail( "you@youremail.com", "Contact Form Submission",
 "Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone: $phone\nWebsite: $url\nMessage: $message\n",
  $headers );
 ?>
```

Comment: Where to add headers? And will this PHP code provided in the question work?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to separate email addresses with commas in the first parameter of the `mail()` function, i.e.

```
mail('email1@example.com, email2@example.com', $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Or sepcific CC and optionally BCC addresses as per Ahmad's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `mail` function (which is used in the code that you posted) allows you to specify multiple recipients. See the PHP documentation of that function for details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

**Edit:** You basically need to replace the `"you@youremail.com"` part with a list of addresses, separated by commas, e.g.:

```
mail("you@youremail.com,somebody@domain.com,anotherone@domain.com", ...
```

Comment: Like I said, I barely know any PHP, and cannot figure my way out alone. Can you please review the php code that I have given in the question and tell me what to add to that to make it work? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: There you go, I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$to = "email@email.com"
$to .= ", anotheremail@email.com";
```

this will help you to create multiple recipient.